# Always save the last object

Tags: ios, swift, object, for-loop, core-data

I want to save the object array into coreData, but just when I use the storeWord () method,It always only deposited in the array of the last object, and I want to put the array of objects are stored in, but I do not know what the problem,Can someone help me? Thank you

Here is my objectArray:

```
var wordArray:[Word] = [
    Word(word: "abacus", pronounce: "ˋæbəkəs", translate: "算盤", image: "abacus.jpg", visited: false),
    Word(word: "abbey", pronounce: "ˋæbɪ", translate: "修道院", image: "abbey.jpg", visited: false),
    Word(word: "ache", pronounce: "ek", translate: "痛", image: "ache.jpg", visited: false)
]
```

The empty CoreData Array:

```
var words:[WordMO] = []
```

Select and store fuction:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  storeWord(wordArray: wordArray)
  getWord()
}

func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}


func storeWord(wordArray:[Word]) {
    let context = getContext()
    var word:WordMO!
    word = WordMO(context: getContext())

    for item in wordArray {
        word.word = item.word
        word.pronounce = item.pronounce
        word.translate = item.translate
        word.visited = item.visited
        if let wordImage = UIImage(named: item.image!) {
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(wordImage,1.0) {
                word.image = NSData(data: imageData)
            }
        }
        words.append(word)

    }
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("success")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate the `WordMO` *inside* the for loop

Comment: @Paulw11I have updated my code,but still did not solve the problem, can help me see if I changed right?

Comment: you need to both alloc and init inside loop. like "let word = WordMO(context: context)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move

```
var word:WordMO!
word = WordMO(context: getContext())
```

into your for loop

Comment: This answer might be correct but it doesn't explain why.

Please write explanation

Comment: The success of the deposit into the! Thank you for the help, but as upstairs said, I do not know why to move to for loop

Comment: @廖豪豪 In your version, your word object is allocated and initialized out side the scope of your for loop. When you append(word) in the for loop, the object added into the list is referring to the same object address. You just updated the object's fields. In the end, the fields info of this object is updated to your last element's information. That's why you see all the words in your list becomes the last word's info. like Surya Subethiran said, you need to both alloc and init inside your loop, then you are adding a new object each time.